# SSH connection to EC2 and RDS with MFA

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, amazon-rds, multi-factor-authentication

in order to improve the security of my aws environment that has an ec2 instance that connect to an RDS in a private subnet, i use a SSH connection. i want to add a MFA to the SSH connection. i should be able to connect to EC2 without problem, but i wonder how would i connect to my RDS database that works on postgres for example, would i be prompted to input the verification code in Pgadmin?
here is a reference of the video to add MFA in EC2. but again the question is , would i still be able to use pgadmin?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iOb6eZJqj-k

Comment: Are you using a SSH tunnel through your EC2 for PostgreSQL?  Are you using password authentication or certificate (pem file) authentication?

Answer (score 1):

This MFA is not related to AWS. This MFA is just plugin for the PAM(
Pluggable Authentication Modules) in linux.

You can use it to enable MFA for SSH. This is optional authentication. It is better option to invest time to hide visibility of your VM to minimum and protect your private keys.

To improve your RDS security enable SSL in your database. After you enable it, your application (and user) requires the SSL certificate to connect your DB. You can read more in the PG docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/ssl-tcp.html

### Important

You should never open `phpPgAdmin` to entire world. You have to limit it at least to VPN, better remove it from server and install(e.g. with docker) only when needed.

Comment: I am using a SSH tunnel through my EC 2  for postgres sql in RDS. I am using certificate (pem file) for authentification. By installing the google authenticication on ec2 , i know that MFA will be required if i connect to ec2  by ssh tunnel. Will i also be required MFA when i connect to pgadmin?

Comment: If you have `phppgadmin` installed on your server and you can visit the WWW page of that tool, Answer is no. Because `One time` password is required only for SSH. For PgAdmin workflow looks: `Web application(on EC2 instance) -> Private AWS Network -> RDS`. This MFA will be required only when you are creating server (to authenticate SSH on your EC2). If you have pgadmin installed `locally` you have to create SSH tunnel for RDS first, then keep it open, and you can connect to your RDS like w/o MFA :)